# Why i'm getting firstDayOfWeek differently in Samsung devices?

Tags: android, gridview, samsung-mobile, android-calendar

I'm using the calendar view for my application. In the below mentioned code, I'm getting the firstdayofweek as 2 in the samsung devices.

```
month = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(),Locale.getDefault());
```

But in all other devices it is coming fine(That is firstdayofweek as 1).

Please find the screen shot as well for the samsung devices.

[image: Value in samsung device]

Because of this issue in samsung devices, the 1st day in the November is showing as Monday, instead of Sunday. I'm facing same issue for other months whose start day/date is Sunday.

Calendar view wrongly showing in samsung device.

[image]

Please help me in correcting this and also where i'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Which specific Samsung devices are you seeing this?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this on my Samsung. You can set the first day of the week on your Calendar and CalendarView, btw, with their respective `setFirstDayOfWeek()` methods.

Comment: @MorrisonChang i'm using Samsung S3

Comment: I should also mention that the default first day of the week is based on the users Locale. (I naively assumed you're in a Sunday first Locale in my last comment.) If you want Sunday as the first day everywhere, then you have to set it as that

Comment: @MikeM. you mean say after doing this month = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(),Locale.getDefault()); should i need to set as month.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);

Comment: Yep. Some Locale's are Monday first, by default. Also, if it really is something to do with the Samsung brand (which I don't think it actually is) then you'd have to set it anyway to correct that.

Comment: @MikeM. i tried but no luck buddy

Comment: Did you set it on the CalendarView as well?

Comment: No i think...Let me check

Comment: Yes, i have added in xml itself.CalendarGridView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"            android:id="@+id/gridview"android:layout_width="fill_parent"android:layout_height="wrap_content"android:background="@android:color/transparent"android:gravity="center"android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
android:listSelector="#00000000"            android:numColumns="7"         android:stretchMode="columnWidth"            android:verticalSpacing="0dp"            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:firstDayOfWeek="1"

Comment: You didn't mention you were using a custom calendar View. What's the `CalendarGridView` class? Unless it extends the regular `CalendarView`, it most likely ignores the `firstDayOfWeek` attribute.

Comment: @Mike CalendarGridview extends gridview, that's it

Comment: Then it's probably ignoring that attribute. Did you write the `CalendarGridView` class? Does it have a `setFirstDayOfWeek()` method?

Comment: @Mike Nope, i didn't write the calendargridview class. It doesn't contain that fucntion. Thanks for your help Mike

Comment: Did you get it figured out?

Comment: When i hard code the week of day to sunday, its working. But as per the requirement i should hard code. And also it is happening only in Galaxy S3 GT I9300 device with OS v4.3. I check in Note 2. Its not happening. I have informed the same to customer as well. Let see...